# Managing explosion of constraints (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, constraints, typeclass

I am writing a function which I would like to be generic over Vectors. In other words, I have something like:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as G
foo :: (G.Vector v a, G.Vector v b, G.Vector v c, G.Vector v d) 
    => v a -> v b -> v c -> v d
```

This way the user gets to choose to use `Unboxed` vs `Storable` Vectors, etc.

But if I need to put intermediate values inside `v`, I get a combinatorical explosion of Vector constraints like:

```
foo :: (G.Vector v a, G.Vector v b, G.Vector v c, G.Vector v d,
        G.Vector v (a, b), G.Vector v (a, c), G.Vector v (c, b))
    => v a -> v b -> v c -> v d
```

How do I manage this verbosity? Is there a way to either have

1) GHC generate the constraints implicitly

2) Refactor the constraints into a common class somehow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A type family could be handy:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, KindSignatures, DataKinds, TypeOperators, ConstraintKinds #-}

import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as G
import GHC.Prim

type family Vectors v (a :: [*]) :: Constraint where
  Vectors v '[]       = ()
  Vectors v (a ': as) = (G.Vector v a, Vectors v as)
```

This creates a type level function that takes a list of types and makes the appropriate constraints for the generic `Vector`s with those types. You can use it like this:

```
foo :: (Vectors v [a, b, c, d, (a, b), (a, c), (c, b)]) => v a -> v b -> v c -> v d
```

This isn't quite ideal, but it does reduce the code to a degree.

### Dealing with the sharp increase in tuple constraints

You can better deal with this explosion of constraints due to pair types with some more type level tricks:

```
type family Combinations v (a :: [*]) :: Constraint where
  Combinations v '[]       = ()
  Combinations v (a ': as) = (G.Vector v a, CombComponent v a as, Combinations v as)

type family CombComponent v (a :: *) (bs :: [*]) :: Constraint where
  CombComponent v a '[]       = ()
  CombComponent v a (b ': bs) = (G.Vector v (a, b), G.Vector v (b, a), CombComponent v a bs)
```

It's a bit more complex, but now we can write that second `foo` signature like this:

```
foo :: (Combinations v [a, b, c, d]) => v a -> v b -> v c -> v d
```

This could also be generalized further to allow for signatures like:

```
foo :: (Combinations (G.Vector v) [a, b, c, d]) => v a -> v b -> v c -> v d
```

Comment: I like the first solution but I think the 2nd would just be incredibly confusing to someone else reading the type signature.

Comment: @user2407038 That's definitely a possibility. I probably could have picked some better names though. It would be easier to read with better names and a couple good comments/a decent haddock explanation (documentation would be important for this sort of trick, I feel).